# Amazon API get browse nodes categories only by search

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I am looking for a way to do a search with the Amazon Product API such as for "cats" and have the api return just the browse nodes that contain products pertaining to the keyword. My intention is to be able to specify a keyword for the website and have it generate the categories that contain related products. I know that I can do an item search with the API and have it return the browseNodes for each given product, but the item search function only returns 10 products at a time and the multiple requests and looping required would be insufficient. Does anyone else know of a way I can just get the categories with available products based off a keyword search?

Answer (score 0):

Getting browsenodes by searching for a keyword search might be difficult as amazon Product API won't provide that information.

You might have already know this however the only way might be uploading all the products and its category in your website DB & relate category and products, and if you search for product it should query in category table and can get the category information.